# Getting the aspect from a raster at a specified lat/long in PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis, raster, postgis-raster

I am looking for a simple example of using `ST_Aspect()` to find the aspect at a specified lat/long pair.

Comment: Not sure why people would down vote this question, but up vote this one: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14960/postgis-raster-value-of-a-lat-lon-point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example returns the [`aspect`](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Aspect.html) of a raster created from a coordinate pair:

```
SELECT 
  ST_Aspect(
    ST_AsRaster('POINT(-4.45 54.36)',1,1));

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0100000100000000000000F03F000000000000F0BFCDCCCCCCCCCC11C0AE47E17A142E4B400000000000000000000000000000000000000000010001004A00000000000080BF
(1 Zeile)
```

Check the [`ST_AsRaster`](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_AsRaster.html) documentation to find the set of parameters that suit your use case.

Comment: I am afraid I am too new to this to understand what I am looking at.  I was expecting the query to return an angle?  Based on this answer, I will edit my question so it better reflects what I am looking for.

Comment: @Craeft have you tried using ST_DumpValues in this resultset? That might show you the result you expect.